# Criar menu dinâmico em VB6

Tags: menu, visual-basic-6

O que parecia ser simples e facil, se tornou um pesadêlo...

A ideia de um menu dinâmico é simples. Basta criar menus,itens e sub-itens de acordo com a base de dados. Entretanto, a ferramenta disponível pelo visual basic 6 é bem limitada e não permite que a construção do menu seja tão dinâmica.

Eu tentei utilizar o componente SmartMenuXP para construir um menu totalmente dinâmico, entretanto, apesar de ter conseguido atingir meu objetivo, houveram alguns problemas que me impediram de progressguir com a utilização deste componente. Essa barra(SmartMenuXp) era alocada no MDI principal do projeto, mas ao abrir formulários filhos, a caixa de controle dos forms filhos ultrapassava o menu e os controles(Minimizar,Fechar,Maximizar) ficavam acima do menu e abaixo dos controles do mdi. Eu busquei toda a informação disponível, li toda a documentacao do produto e varri todas as propriedades... mas nao consegui solucionar o problema.

Gostaria de encontrar uma API/Componente de facil utilizacao para criar uma barra de menus, ou menus diâmicos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Infelizmente o VB6 não permite fazer isso utilizando apena o VB. Deve ser utilizado um componente externo ou as API's do Windows.

Criei um pequeno exemplo de como fazer isso utilizando as API's do Windows.

Para o exemplo foi criado um `Form` (`Form1`) e um `Module` (`Module1`).

Inicialmente, o `Form1` possui a seguinte barra de menus:

[image: Form1]

Durante a execução do programa, o exemplo adiciona um separador e três menus extras:

[image: Form1 com menus dinâmicos]

O `Module1` tem as seguintes funções importantes para o `Form1`:

- `PreparaForm1`: prepara o `Form1` para poder adicionar e tratar menus dinâmicos
- `AdicionaItem`: adiciona um item a um menu existente (por segurança, para não conflitar com os id's dos menus nativos do VB, escolha id's altos, como 16000, 16001 ... até 65534)
- `AdicionaSubMenu`: adiciona um item a um menu existente, porém esse item agirá como um submenu
- `AdicionaSeparador`: adiciona um separador a um menu existente
- `RemoveItemPorIndice`: remove um item (conforme seu índice/posição) de um menu existente
- `RemoveItemPorId`: remove um item (conforme seu id) de um menu existente

Há ainda quatro outras funções para trabalhar com items em submenus, elas funcionam da mesma forma que as outras, mas agem sobre um submenu, dentro de um menu: `AdicionaItemSub`, `AdicionaSeparadorSub`, `RemoveItemPorIndiceSub` e `RemoveItemPorIdSub`

## Código do Form1 de Exemplo

```
Option Explicit

Public Function MenuClicado(ByVal id As Long) As Boolean
    MenuClicado = True

    Select Case id
    Case 16001
        MsgBox "Menu dinâmico 1: vou excluir o menu no índice 1"
        'Exclui o menu com o índice 1
        Module1.RemoveItemPorIndice 0, 1
    Case 16002
        MsgBox "Menu dinâmico 2: vou excluir o Menu dinâmico 3"
        'Exclui o Menu dinâmico 3 através do seu id
        Module1.RemoveItemPorId 0, 16003
    Case 16003
        MsgBox "Menu dinâmico 3"
    Case 16004
        MsgBox "Sub item 1"
    Case 16005
        MsgBox "Sub item 2"
    Case 16006
        MsgBox "Sub item 3"
    Case Else
        'Não era um dos nossos menus
        MenuClicado = False
    End Select
End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()
    'Primeiro deve preparar o módulo!!!
    Module1.PreparaForm1 Me

    'Adiciona um separador ao menu 0 (primeiro menu)
    Module1.AdicionaSeparador 0

    'Adiciona três items ao menu 0 (primeiro menu)
    Module1.AdicionaItem 0, 16001, "Menu dinâmico 1"
    Module1.AdicionaItem 0, 16002, "Menu dinâmico 2"
    Module1.AdicionaItem 0, 16003, "Menu dinâmico 3"
    Module1.AdicionaSubMenu 0, "Menu dinâmico 4"
    Module1.AdicionaItemSub 0, 5, 16004, "Sub item 1"
    Module1.AdicionaItemSub 0, 5, 16005, "Sub item 2"
    Module1.AdicionaItemSub 0, 5, 16006, "Sub item 3"
End Sub
```

## Código do Module1

```
Option Explicit

'API's do Windows para trabalhar com menus
Private Const MF_SEPARATOR As Long = &H800
Private Const MF_BYPOSITION As Long = &H400
Private Const MF_POPUP As Long = &H10
Private Declare Function GetMenu Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetSubMenu Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hMenu As Long, ByVal nPos As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function AppendMenu Lib "user32.dll" Alias "AppendMenuA" (ByVal hMenu As Long, ByVal uFlags As Long, ByVal uIDNewItem As Long, ByVal lpNewItem As String) As Long
Private Declare Function RemoveMenu Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hMenu As Long, ByVal uPosition As Long, ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CreatePopupMenu Lib "user32.dll" () As Long

'API's do Windows para trabalhar com janelas e mensagens
Private Const WM_COMMAND As Long = &H111
Private Const GWL_WNDPROC As Long = -4
Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CallWindowProc Lib "user32.dll" Alias "CallWindowProcA" (ByVal lpPrevWndFunc As Long, ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal message As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

'Endereço do WndProc antigo do Form
Private oldWndProc As Long
Private frmOriginal As Form1

Public Sub PreparaForm1(frm As Form1)
    Set frmOriginal = frm

    'Esse código todo tem que vir aqui em um módulo separado por causa
    'do operador AddressOf
    oldWndProc = SetWindowLong(frm.hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, AddressOf WndProc)
End Sub

Public Sub AdicionaItem(ByVal indiceDoMenuPai As Long, ByVal id As Long, ByVal texto As String)
    Dim barraDeMenus As Long
    barraDeMenus = GetMenu(frmOriginal.hWnd)

    Dim menu As Long
    menu = GetSubMenu(barraDeMenus, indiceDoMenuPai)

    AppendMenu menu, 0, id, texto
End Sub

Public Sub AdicionaItemSub(ByVal indiceDoMenuPai As Long, ByVal indiceDoSubMenu As Long, ByVal id As Long, ByVal texto As String)
    Dim barraDeMenus As Long
    barraDeMenus = GetMenu(frmOriginal.hWnd)

    Dim menu As Long
    menu = GetSubMenu(barraDeMenus, indiceDoMenuPai)
    menu = GetSubMenu(menu, indiceDoSubMenu)

    AppendMenu menu, 0, id, texto
End Sub

Public Sub AdicionaSeparador(ByVal indiceDoMenuPai As Long)
    Dim barraDeMenus As Long
    barraDeMenus = GetMenu(frmOriginal.hWnd)

    Dim menu As Long
    menu = GetSubMenu(barraDeMenus, indiceDoMenuPai)

    AppendMenu menu, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, ""
End Sub

Public Sub AdicionaSeparadorSub(ByVal indiceDoMenuPai As Long, ByVal indiceDoSubMenu As Long)
    Dim barraDeMenus As Long
    barraDeMenus = GetMenu(frmOriginal.hWnd)

    Dim menu As Long
    menu = GetSubMenu(barraDeMenus, indiceDoMenuPai)
    menu = GetSubMenu(menu, indiceDoSubMenu)

    AppendMenu menu, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, ""
End Sub

Public Sub AdicionaSubMenu(ByVal indiceDoMenuPai As Long, ByVal texto As String)
    Dim barraDeMenus As Long
    barraDeMenus = GetMenu(frmOriginal.hWnd)

    Dim menu As Long
    menu = GetSubMenu(barraDeMenus, indiceDoMenuPai)

    AppendMenu menu, MF_POPUP, CreatePopupMenu, texto
End Sub

Public Sub RemoveItemPorIndice(ByVal indiceDoMenuPai As Long, ByVal indiceDoItem As Long)
    Dim barraDeMenus As Long
    barraDeMenus = GetMenu(frmOriginal.hWnd)

    Dim menu As Long
    menu = GetSubMenu(barraDeMenus, indiceDoMenuPai)

    RemoveMenu menu, indiceDoItem, MF_BYPOSITION
End Sub

Public Sub RemoveItemPorIndiceSub(ByVal indiceDoMenuPai As Long, ByVal indiceDoSubMenu As Long, ByVal indiceDoItem As Long)
    Dim barraDeMenus As Long
    barraDeMenus = GetMenu(frmOriginal.hWnd)

    Dim menu As Long
    menu = GetSubMenu(barraDeMenus, indiceDoMenuPai)
    menu = GetSubMenu(menu, indiceDoSubMenu)

    RemoveMenu menu, indiceDoItem, MF_BYPOSITION
End Sub

Public Sub RemoveItemPorId(ByVal indiceDoMenuPai As Long, ByVal idDoItem As Long)
    Dim barraDeMenus As Long
    barraDeMenus = GetMenu(frmOriginal.hWnd)

    Dim menu As Long
    menu = GetSubMenu(barraDeMenus, indiceDoMenuPai)

    RemoveMenu menu, idDoItem, 0
End Sub

Public Sub RemoveItemPorIdSub(ByVal indiceDoMenuPai As Long, ByVal indiceDoSubMenu As Long, ByVal idDoItem As Long)
    Dim barraDeMenus As Long
    barraDeMenus = GetMenu(frmOriginal.hWnd)

    Dim menu As Long
    menu = GetSubMenu(barraDeMenus, indiceDoMenuPai)
    menu = GetSubMenu(menu, indiceDoSubMenu)

    RemoveMenu menu, idDoItem, 0
End Sub

Private Function WndProc(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal message As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
    If message = WM_COMMAND Then
        If frmOriginal.MenuClicado(wParam And &HFFFF) = True Then
            'Quando um dos nossos menus foi clicado, apenas retorna 0,
            'e para a função por aqui
            WndProc = 0
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
    'Chama o WndProc antigo do Form
    WndProc = CallWindowProc(oldWndProc, hWnd, message, wParam, lParam)
End Function
```

Comment: Muito grato pela ajuda.

Entretanto, o projeto em questao possui um menu composto por: Menu -> Item -> SubItem e através desta solução eu só consigo chegar ao nivel de ITEM.

Comment: Na verdade, @CleitonRibeiro, é só adaptar o `Module1`. Estou entrando para dar aula agora. Para o final da tarde posto uma atualuzação :)

Comment: Poxa carlos, obrigado... estava dando uma olhada no codigo, sinceramente nao sei o que fazer. Aguardo tua atualização, muito obrigado.

Comment: Prontinho, @CleitonRibeiro, atualizado. Para fazer mais níveis de submenu, é só seguir o esquema das funções para submenu ;)

Comment: carlos,muito grato. Me ajudou muito!